# Filtering out empty entries in a nested list

Tags: python, list, loops

So I have a list of lists L that I'm iterating over trying to filter out the duplicates. Now I am aware this isn't the best method to do this but its what was specifically asked for. I don't end up with duplicate data but I do end up with duplicate empty columns that I haven't been able to fix, any help?

```
for x in range(len(L), 0, -1): 
x -= 1 #len() 
for y in range(len(L[0]), 0, -1):
    y -= 1 
    if y != 0 and y != 1: #Skiping Coloumns 0 and 1
        check = L[x][y]
        for x0 in range(len(L), 0, -1):
            x0 -= 1 
            for y0 in range(len(L[0]), 0, -1):
                y0 -= 1 
                if y0 == y:
                    checkagainst = L[x0][y0]
                    if check == checkagainst:
                        if x != x0: #If its on the same row, don't count bro
                            #print "Identical Indices:","X0:",x0,",","Y0:", y0,"|" ,"X:",x,",","Y:",y
                            #print L[x][y], "," , L[x0][y0]
                            WriteMe = True #Write to Not Duplicate file or not decider
                            if check == "": ##Didnt work
                                WriteMe = False
        print x, ",", y
if WriteMe == True:
    dwriter.writerow(L[x])
    WriteMe = False #Set to False for next iteration
else:
    writer.writerow(L[x])
L.pop(x)
print
```

Sample input:

```
ID, Sex, E-mail

1, M, lol@jk.com

2, F, 

3, F,

4, F, jack@jay.com
```

Expected Output(None Duplicate File):

```
Id, Sex, E-mail

1, M, lol@jk.com

2, F,

4, jack@jay.com
```

(ID 2 and ID 3 are interchangeable in this scenario because they are the duplicate rows)

Expected Output(Duplicate File):

```
ID, Sex, E-mail

3, F,
```

Comment: Post a sample input and expected output.

Comment: Are they duplicates if they have the same email and but a different sex?

Comment: @2rs2ts no I'm only filtering for the e-mail. As long as they have different e-mail addresses they're not duplicates.

Comment: Instead of all those statements that fiddle an index by 1, just adjust the bounds of your `range`s. Also, your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Don't loop over the columns if you only care about one column. Just look at that specific column.

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the L variable ? I'm sure there is a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
with open('abc') as f:
    #next(f)       #skip header if present
    for line in f:
        data = map(str.strip, line.split(', '))
        idx, sex, mail = data if len(data) == 3 else data+['']
        dic.setdefault(mail,[]).append([idx,sex])
...
```

**Non-Duplicate:**

```
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    print ", ".join((v[0][0],v[0][1],k))
...     
1, M, lol@jk.com
2, F, 
4, F, jack@jay.com
```

**Duplicate:**

```
for k,v in dic.iteritems():
    if len(v) >1:
        for v1 in v[1:]:
            print ", ".join((v1[0],v1[1],k))
...             
3, F,,
```

Comment: I think OP wanted 3 to be in the separate file, not 2. Easy enough to check `if mail in dic` and to put that in a list if so.

Comment: @2rs2ts OP said `id2` and `id3` are interchangeable, btw I've updated my solution.